# A doubt about Proposition $27$ in textbook Algebra by Saunders MacLane and Garrett Birkhoff

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

I'm reading **Proposition 27** in textbook *Algebra* by Saunders MacLane and Garrett Birkhoff.

[image]

> If $N \trianglelefteq G$ and $S \subseteq G$, the join $N \vee S$ consists of all products $ns$ for $n \in N$ and $s \in S$. If both $N \cap S = \{1\}$ and $N \lor S=G$, then $G / N \cong S$.

Because the result is $G / N \cong S$, I think $S$ must be a subgroup, not just a subset of $G$. As such, I think it should be clearer to write $S \le G$, i.e. $S$ is a subgroup of $G$, rather than $S \subseteq G$.

Could you please verify if my observation is fine?

---

**Update:** I added the part that the authors define *subgroup*. I still feel that the use of $\subseteq$ for both subset and subgroup is confusing.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The use of the letter $S$ implies subset. Does the book use $<$ for subgroup elsewhere? If so, the question is probably correct as stated. (I have not tried to prove it.)

Comment: @user1729 please see my edit.

Comment: The result is wrong if $S$ is just a subset. For example, if $G=S_5$, $N=A_5$, and $S=\{e,(1,2),(1,3)\}$, then the join of $N$ and $S$ is $G$, the intersection of $N$ and $S$ is trivial, but $G/N$ is not “isomorphic” to $S$ because $S$ is not a subgroup.

Comment: Well, the next question is: do they ever use the symbol $\subset$ to mean subset? It looks like they are defining $\subset$ to mean subgroup. (Also, this book is not new, and notation had a habit of changing over time, and even between subject areas, so this notation may have been standard then. Certainly, I have seen it used to mean subgroup in older paper.)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Please transfer your comment into an answer so that I can accept it and remove it from list of unanswered questions?

Comment: (Also, I notice that this is a proposition, not an exercise. So it has a proof, right? When you are unclear about this sort of thing it is a nice exercise to read the proof to work out what the statement *should* be.)

Comment: @user1729 please see my edit again. The proof appeals to the inverse of an element in $S$, so $\subset$ should mean subgroup in this case.

Comment: For what it’s worth, Mac Lane and Birkhoff had three books: “A survey of algebra” and “A brief survey of algebra”, both of which list Birkhoff first and Mac Lane second (so the former is known as “Birkhoff-Mac Lane”), and “Algebra”, which seems to be the one you have and which lists Mac Lane first. It is “Survey” (not “Brief survey”) which is generally considered the better book.

Comment: Thank you so much for your elaboration @ArturoMagidin! I chose *Algebra* rather than *A Survey of Modern Algebra* because I prefer the definition of determinant in a more abstract from in the former. IMHO, the definition of determinant based on alternating multilinear maps is more general and thus elagant.

Comment: (Oops; I *think* it is “A survey of **modern** algebra” and “A brief survey of **modern** algebra”... and it’s too late to edit the previous comment).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I'm sure we are talking about the same textbook ^^ https://www.amazon.com/Survey-Modern-Algebra-Akp-Classics/dp/1568810687

Comment: @ArturoMagidin It's quite weird for me that a textbook of algebra mentions systems of numbers and polynomials before defining groups, rings, and fields ^_^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the remarks following Proposition 27, the authors state

> In such cases, when $N \cap S = 1$ and $N \vee S = G,$ the subgroup $S$ is called a "complement" of the normal subgroup $N.$

This makes it clear that they intended $S$ to be a subgroup. As Arturo points out, the proposition is not valid without this assumption.